# Formula works in excel, but name does not

Tags: excel

I have this formula in excel, to return a row number:

`=MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4)),DayOffRequests!$A$1:$A$100,0)`

and it works just fine.

I would like to make a new name (`DAYS_OFF_ROW`) and assign it to this formula.

Here's what I did in the name manager:

[image: Name Manager]

But when I write this into a cell: `=DAYS_OFF_ROW` it says `#VALUE!` whereas when I write the same formula into the cell, it gives me the row number I am looking for.

Why is does it say `#VALUE!` and not the row number like the formula does?

Comment: try when you create the name, to include the cell in row(), e.g. select A1, go to the name manager and enter `=MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(A1),4)),DayOffRequests!$A$1:$A$100,0)`

Comment: That sounded like a good idea @nutsch but it didnt work... :-\

Answer (score 0):

First off Row() returns the row on which the cell resides. If you put Row() in indirect you will get an error since there is no cell for which Excel can find a Row(). So right off the bat, your formula is nonsense for a named range.

Second, even if there was some magic way for Excel to know which `Row()` you cared about here, `Match` doesn't return a range. Just a position in an array like "5" or "50". When you use a formula to define a named range, the result of the formula MUST be a range. So you could do another `Indirect` like `=Indirect("A" & Match(foo,bar))` or something so that the result out of your formula actually refers to a range in your sheet.

Comment: I cant quite follow all your suggestions. But you realize that my formula works the way i want it to, when i use it on the sheet, right? But you are saying that row() wont work for names?

Comment: If you put `=Row()` in cell `A1` it will return `1`. If you put `=Row()` in cell `Z5` it will return `5`. Now you put `=Row()` in the formula of a named range. Which row do you expect it to return? It can't return anything because it's not in a cell, it's in a formula stuck inside the named range manager. In the end you have two issues. `Row()` won't work here, and no matter what formula you stick in the Named Range MAnager formula box, it must return a Range so that the name manager can give that range a name. `Match()` doesn't return a range, just a number.

Answer (score 0):

It works if i set the name to this formula: `=MATCH(!$D1,DayOffRequests!$A$1:$A$100,0)`
 Of course i have to be in field A1 when setting the name. Now its reference the fourth column and whichever row i am in.